# How to reload MKAnnotations without reloading MapView?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I have an app which searches using a Web service for informations about stations, then I get the response JSON. But each time I change the position of the center I have to reload the pins and add new ones, even if they are already on the map.

I can get the response JSON, get the information to display and create the annotations. The problem is when I move the center, it reloads the annotations over the others.

Comment: are you calling `[map removeAnnotations:map.annotations];` before adding new pins?

Comment: Yes, I was doing that, but it reloads every time I move center and locks it, and I cant move... Its like looping forever.

Comment: Thanks you Mat, I have now my method rocking. Thanks for giving me the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is I was inserting that method in the method that makes the connection to the web service or when i receive the response...

But I inserted the method in this one in the first line:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapViewStation viewForAnnotation:(id      <MKAnnotation>)annotation

[map removeAnnotations:map.annotations];

//Code
```

It rocks. Thanks